Prompt users to update version from google play console
I try to Prompt users to update version via google play console.
And then I found this link https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13812041?hl=en#zippy=%2Cedit-update%2Cview-recovery-progress.
After try to implement it, the button submit in Prompt users to update modal google play console is disabled.

Do you guys know why the submit button is disabled?

Because it is your latest production build. try with your currently using build (73>)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
